# Making a AC3 LinkButton look like an HTML link

Tags: actionscript-3, mxml, linkbutton

I am still new to using AC3 and its workings. I am attempting to mimic the sort of link button that is standard with HTML/CSS and have found the mx:LinkButton class. However, when using it I get the halo look of the button and am not sure how I can maintain the properties of the button but modify it slightly to look like the HTML version.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Try setting upSkin to overSkin.

Or upIcon to overIcon.